# No carga vista en Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, component, angular6

cree dos componentes dentro de Angular entonces tengo dos archivos de modulos el archivo app.module llamo al archivo pages.module que tiene el resto de modulos.

app.module.ts

> ```
>  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
>  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
> import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-        browser/animations';
>        import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
>   import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
>   import { MatButtonModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
>   import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
>   import 'hammerjs';
>   import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
>   import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
>   import { FuseProgressBarModule, FuseSidebarModule, FuseThemeOptionsModule } 
>  from '@fuse/components';
>  import { fuseConfig } from 'app/fuse-config';
>  import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
>  import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
>  import { SampleModule } from 'app/main/sample/sample.module';
>  const appRoutes: Routes = [
> {
>     path      : '**',
>     redirectTo: 'sample'
> },
> {
>     path        : 'pages',
>     loadChildren: './main/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' 
> }
> ```
>
> ];

```
 @NgModule({
     declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports     : [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

    TranslateModule.forRoot(),

    // Material moment date module
    MatMomentDateModule,

    // Material
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,

    // Fuse modules
    FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
    FuseProgressBarModule,
    FuseSharedModule,
    FuseSidebarModule,
    FuseThemeOptionsModule,

    // App modules
    LayoutModule,
    SampleModule
],
bootstrap   : [
    AppComponent
]
 })
 export class AppModule
 {
 }
```

pages.module.ts

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
>   import { ProfileModule } from 'app/main/pages/profile/profile.module';
>   import { CrudexpedienteModule } from './expedientes/crud-expediente/crud-expediente.module';
>   @NgModule({
> imports: [
>     // Profile
>     ProfileModule,
>     CrudexpedienteModule
>      ]
>    })
>    export class PagesModule
>      {
>      }
> ```

Pero no se que me falta para que me cargue la vista del componente en cuta organizacion la tengo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el archivo navigation que es el encargado de dar la ruta de los hipervinculos a la izquierda

```
import { FuseNavigation } from '@fuse/types';

export const navigation: FuseNavigation[] = [
{
    id       : 'applications',
    title    : 'Applications',
    translate: 'NAV.APPLICATIONS',
    type     : 'group',
    children : [
        {
            id       : 'sample',
            title    : 'Sample',
            translate: 'NAV.SAMPLE.TITLE',
            type     : 'item',
            icon     : 'email',
            url      : '/sample',
            badge    : {
                title    : '25',
                translate: 'NAV.SAMPLE.BADGE',
                bg       : '#F44336',
                fg       : '#FFFFFF'
            }
        },
        {
            id   : 'profile',
            title: 'Profile',
            type : 'item',
            icon : 'person',
            url  : '/pages/profile'
        },
        {
            id   : 'crud-expediente',
            title: 'Expedientes',
            type : 'item',
            icon : 'person',
            url  : '/pages/expedientes/crud-expediente'
        }
    ]
}
```

];

Cuando cargo el aplicattivo aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono cualquiera de las paginas no me direcciona se queda ahi en esa.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que sucede actualmente? ¿Página en blanco? ¿Errores en consola? Provee más detalles.

Comment: @IARAPRO de que parte de colombia eres :D

Comment: Ya hay mas detalles

Comment: ¿Has importado en el módulo del sidebar el módulo `RouterModule`? Así mismo, asegúrate que los elementos `<a>` tengan el atributo `routerLink`.

Comment: si porque se supone que en el archivo app.module.ts al RouterModule le paso un arreglo donde esta el pagesModule

Comment: Verifique todo eso y esta bien pero no se que falla porque en la consola del navegador no me dice nada

Answer (score 2):

Espero no sea tarde. Esta aplicando rutas a módulos y deben tener sus rutas a componentes o a otros módulos.

**PAGES MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileModule } from 'app/main/pages/profile/profile.module';
import { CrudexpedienteModule } from './expedientes/crud-expediente/crud-expediente.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path        : 'profile',
        loadChildren: './directorio del archivo/profile.module#ProfileModule'
    },
    {
        path        : 'expedientes',
        loadChildren: './directorio del archivo/crud-expediente.module#CrudExpedienteModule'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ProfileModule,
    CrudexpedienteModule
    ]
})
export class PagesModule {}
```

**PROFILE MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path        : '',
        loadChildren: './directorio del archivo/profile.component'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ProfileComponent
    ]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

**CRUD EXPEDIENTE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudExpedienteComponent } from './crud-expediente.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path        : 'crud-expediente',
        loadChildren: './directorio del archivo/crud-expediente.component'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    CrudExpedienteComponent
    ]
})
export class CrudExpedienteModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

no veo que hayas añadido el modulo "PagesModule" en app.module.ts por lo que entiendo que angular no tiene visibilidad soobre ese modulo y es por eso que no lo ves, entendiendo que ese sea tu problema.

Comment: Leandro Seonae, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).